# Ruby's spaceship operator gives the opposite result

Tags: ruby

When comparing these strings

```
book_1 = "A Wrinkle in Time"
book_2 = "A Brief History of Time"

book_1 <=> book_2 #=> 1
```

I get a `1` which is confusing to me, since the [doc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) says:

> If the strings are of different lengths, and the strings are equal when compared up to the shortest length, then the longer string is considered greater than the shorter one.

with the sample code:

```
"abcdef" <=> "abcde"     #=> 1
"abcdef" <=> "abcdef"    #=> 0
"abcdef" <=> "abcdefg"   #=> -1
"abcdef" <=> "ABCDEF"    #=> 1
```

Shouldn't the answer be `-1` since the string on the right is longer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the key in your case:

> and the strings are equal when compared up to the shortest length

Strings `A Wrinkle in Time` and `A Brief History of Time` are not equal at all, they start to diff already at 3rd symbol (`W` from `Wrinkle` vs `B` from `Brief`) and since `W` > `B` you get `1`, i.e. first string is bigger than the second.

Comment: That makes me feel stupid. Thank you. It confused me and another ruby dev I asked, that's why I posted it here.

Comment: @amingilani Don't be, we are all have been there :)

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood. It is `1`, because in `book_1` 3<sup>rd</sup> character `W` is bigger than 3<sup>rd</sup> character`B` in `book2`. That is why even though they are different of length, but *and the strings are equal when compared up to the shortest length* doesn't hold. - This matched the as documented.

`-1` is the answer, when you have `"abcdef"` and `"abcdefg"`. Now see, left hand strings characters are same upto the chars `"abcdef"` of the longer one. Then the right hand string has more characters, which makes the output of `"abcdef" <=> "abcdefg"` to `-1`. - This matched the as documented.

Answer (score 0):

```
book_1 = "A Wrinkle in Time"
book_2 = "A Brief History of Time"
```

In your example, the strings aren't the same for the entire length of the shorter string. Ruby's sort will compare the characters at 2nd index "W" <=> "B" in which case "B" is less than "W".